# Creating a Persistent Local Table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've seen a few questions that are close to mine, but not exact, so I'm hoping that I haven't just missed a duplicate.

I have to run a daily job that looks for records that have changed in a very specific manner, but our current database has no CDC and there is no link to the server with the day-old backups. I need a way to store the primary key for one of our tables in such a way that it will be accessible the next morning after having logged off at night (logging off is unfortunately non-negotiable, as this is at work). I do not have write access for tempdb, which is so far the only method I've come across that will allow this.

Is there another method for storing a local 'temp' table that is persistent across logins? It's fine if it is specific to my machine.

---

Failing this being possible, another solution I've come up with is to store the primary keys in a text file each night, and format them into a list to use in a query, but there are between 35,000-40,000 of them in question and I'm not sure if SQL Server will be brought to its knees by pasting that many integers into an `IN` clause.

---

### Edit:

I am not on the tech side of the business, so I do not have **any** administrative rights whatsoever. I am just a user of the db in question.

Comment: In response to part 2 of my question, SSMS 2012 can easily handle a list of 45,000 integers in an `IN` clause, but apparently only if the list is broken up vertically instead of a one-line list. The list can be very easily created using substitution expressions in vim.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a local database with a linked server (pointed at your server db).

Then, each night, just `select` from the table on the linked server into a local table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the appropriate rights you could create a daily job that creates and populates the local table with the desired values.